# ¿Como eliminar un caracter escrito por consola en Java?

Tags: java

**Hay alguna manera de eliminar un caracter escrito por consola con `System.out` o `System.err`?**

---

Por ejemplo si tengo un proceso que carga durante un rato, simular una animación con los 3 puntos suspensivos `...`. Algo parecido a esta **[demo en fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjtnmsck/)**.

```
int puntos = 0;
final String PUNTO = ".";
System.out.print("Conectando, espera");

while (condicionQueSeCumplaAlAcabarElProceso) {
    if (puntos < 3) {                       // comprobar cuantos puntos hay
        System.out.print(PUNTO);            // poner un punto
        puntos ++;                          // indicarlo
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);             // esperar 1 segundo
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    } else {
        // aqui hay que borrar los 3 puntos ¿como se hace?
        puntos = 0;                         // resetear
    }
}
```

Comment: No sé cómo se insertan caracteres especiales en Java, pero este te puede servir https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lo que buscas es el caracter `\b` que es el `retroceso` o `backspace`.

Usándolo para borrar los tres puntos `...` como tu ejemplo, sería:

```
int puntos = 0;
final String PUNTO = ".";
System.out.print("Conectando, espera");

while (condicionQueSeCumplaAlAcabarElProceso) {
    if (puntos < 3) {                       // comprobar cuantos puntos hay
        System.out.print(PUNTO);            // poner un punto
        puntos ++;                          // indicarlo
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);             // esperar 1 segundo
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    } else {
        // aqui hay que borrar los 3 puntos ¿como se hace?
        puntos = 0;                         // resetear
        System.out.print('\b\b\b');
    }
}
```

Un ejemplo de cómo usarlo con números para representar el porcentaje sería:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.print("Progreso: ");
    for (int percentage = 0; percentage < 100; percentage++) {
        System.out.print(percentage + "%");
        Thread.sleep(1000); //Simulamos que algo tardado pasa acá
        int length = String.valueOf(percentage).length() + 1;
        while (length-- > 0) {
            System.out.print('\b');
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Proceso finalizado!");
}
```

**Importante:** La consola debe soportar el caracter `\b`. Algunas consolas (como las de los IDE) no lo soportan por defecto.

Comment: Esto funciona en todos los OS?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Si luiggi porque java corre sobre su propia JVM , de manera tal que es independiente del SO

Comment: @Santi92 acabo de revisar esto: [Java backspace escape](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3328824/1065197) e indica que esto depende de la consola y no de la JVM o del OS. Se puede decir que se espera que el caracter `\b` funcione siempre y cuando la consola lo soporte.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza puede ser, pero no es a lo que apunta la pregunta.

Comment: @Santi92 pero es importante resaltarlo para que no hayan sorpresas cuando alguien vea un caracter extraño en lugar de ver que el caracter se ha eliminado, lo cual suele suceder al ejecutar tu aplicación Java en un IDE como Eclipse o NetBeans.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza esta bien la aclaración, sugiere una edición

Comment: Sugiere una edición y le doy aceptar. Me parece buena observación.

Answer (score 1):

Este es un ejemplo de lo que deseas, basado en lo que comparte nuestro amigo Gepser, es importante el uso de `\b` para la eliminación del caracter "`.`" :

```
        System.out.println("Inicia proceso.");
        System.out.print("Conectando, espera");
        int puntos = 0;
        final String PUNTO = ".";
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter < 100) {
            if (puntos < 3) {                       
                System.out.print(PUNTO);            
                puntos ++;                          
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);             
                } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                puntos = 0;                         
                System.out.print("\b\b\b   \b\b\b");
                System.out.flush();
            }
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.println("\nTermina proceso!");
```

Imprime los puntos uno por uno y después los borra para iniciar la secuencia, anexo [**demo aquí**](http://goo.gl/p6d4hp)

salida:

```
Conectando, espera.
Conectando, espera..
Conectando, espera...
Conectando, espera.
Conectando, espera..
Conectando, espera...
...
...
...
Termina proceso!
```